# Why is Microsoft Visual Studio accessing my microphone?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, microphone, privacy

I am curious, roughly 2 weeks ago Visual Studio started to use my microphone.
Has anybody seen the same behavior and knows why that happens?

[image]

Since my softwarephone is an desktop app too I can't disable microphone access for desktop apps.

Checked so far:

- Audio cues are disabled:

[image]

Comment: Do you have "audio cues" turned on? You can find the option in Options -> Text Editor -> General.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to me, unfortunately the audio cues are disabled.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't use the microphone by itself. Have you installed any dictation, speech recognition or accessibility tools? There's a Copilot Voice Assistant for VS Code too, I don't know if there's one for VS as well